# How to create transitions in adobe flash?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, animation, adobe-flash

I'm creating an animation in Flash CC. I would like to add some transitions to it like fade in/fade out etc. I'm not sure how to do this in flash.

Comment: Can you tell us what you have tried, what resources you have exhaused and where you get stuck? Please provide some relevant screenshots too. Transitions in Flash should be straightforward; a quick search gives you several tutorials. If these does not solve it, you must provide us with a good deal more of information.

Answer (score 1):

Fade in Fade out Transition can be made by Motion and Alpha Properties.
Wipe Effect Transition can be made by Masking Properties.
Iris Effects Transition can be made by Shape Tween.
with the Help of Action Scripting you can also make many of the transition effects.
 For This all You need to have knowledge of Basics In Flash and then you can make thousands of Transition effects in this Software.

Answer (score 0):

Animating opacity transitions in Flash is done the same way that movements are animated: starting state and frame, ending state and frame, apply the tween and whatever easing you need.

Alpha properties are accessible through the Properties Panel, under the `Color Effect` tab. In the `Style` dropdown, you'll find Brightness, Tint, Alpha and "Advanced," which exposes RGBA values. All of these can be animated, no differently from motion.

If any of the above is mysterious to you, then you've stumbled into the wrong place. You would be better served by studying some tutorials on Flash basics first, then asking specific questions here.